# FreeRadius Configuration (radiusd.conf) - Regex-Problem unlang

Tags: regex, regex-group, freeradius, radius

I am currently facing a problem within my Radius configuration and wanted to ask you for help.

I'am using the `FreeRadius-Version 3.0.23`

Within the `authorize` section in `radiusd.conf` I am trying to create the following unlang expression.

I have users in the following format:

```
super1
super2
...
user1
user2
```

**NAS-Identifier:**

```
SUP-A
SUP-B
SUP-C
SUP-D
```

I want to extract something from the NAS identifier using a regex and append to the user.

```
=> super1-A
=> super2-D
```

However, it doesn't work with the following expression because the extracted value is no longer available in the second IF statement.

```
if ( NAS-Identifier =~ /^SUP\\-([ABCD])/ ) {

=> The extracted value is only available at this point
=> Or is it possible to define a local variable with the value?

    if ( "%{User-Name}" !~ /^super\\d+/ )
            update request {                                                                                                         
                User-Name := "%{User-Name}-%{1}"   (However, I need the value here)                                                                                                                                                                                     
            }                                                                                                                        
        }
    }
```

This is my workaround:

```
if ( "%{User-Name}" !~ /^super\\d+/ && NAS-Identifier =~ /^SUP\\-([ABCD])/ ) {
            update request {                                                                                                         
                User-Name := "%{User-Name}-%{1}"                                                                                                                                                                                        
            }                                                                                                                        
        }
```

I would really appreciate your help as I couldn't find anything in the FreeRadius documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Every time a regular expression is evaluated, whether it matches or not, the capture group values will be cleared.* Can't you change the order of `if`s? `if ( "%{User-Name}" !~ /^super\\d+/ ) { if ( NAS-Identifier =~ /^SUP\\-([ABCD])/ ) ...`

Comment: Dzienkuje @Wiktor Stribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [FreeRadius documentation](https://freeradius.org/radiusd/man/unlang.html#lbAH):

> Every time a regular expression is evaluated, whether it matches or not, the capture group values will be cleared.

So, in your case, you can reverse the order of conditions:

```
if ( "%{User-Name}" !~ /^super\\d+/ ) {
  if ( NAS-Identifier =~ /^SUP-([ABCD])/ ) {
    update request {                                                                                                         
      User-Name := "%{User-Name}-%{1}" 
    }                                                                                                                        
  }
}
```

Note that the `-` char is not any special regex metacharacter when used outside character classes, no need to escape it here.